# How can I Implement Yelp's Map Search and Search by zip code or by city name

Tags: django, google-maps, geolocation, location, zipcode

How can I implement yelp like search?

There are 2 types of searches on yelp.

1. Simple search using the zip code, city and state in U.S.

   I'm using PostgreSQL and wonder if there is good dataset that I can use that has city, state and zip code. I was hoping to find a good geo shape file and use geoDjango where I can just use, say Store.objects.filter(coordinates__in=cityNameORZipCode).

   There seem to be some zip code database that I can use, but I really don't know where I can find a good city, state. The last option is to create my own cityname and state table and link to Stores, but not sure if this is smart thing to do.....hm.
2. Yelp has map search.

   If you zoom in or out the google map, it searches local businesses according to the map area you are viewing. Think this is amazing. How can I do this?

It's looking dark right now. Please shed me some light.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a very broad and unanswerable question, but a good place to start for data in the U.S. is at the Census Bureau. For example:

- [State and State Equivalent Areas](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/st2000.html)
- [County and County Equivalent Areas](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/co2000.html)

The full list:

- http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/bdy_files.html